# How do I access variables from the csma.c file? - Contiki

Tags: contiki

I am working on a routing mechanism that uses information from the MAC layer in Contiki. Therefore, I need to read variables in the csma.c file. So, my question is how is the best way to access variables in this file?

For example, I want to take statistics about the average delay when scheduling a transmission. To that end, I have to read the variable **delay** in the function **schedule_transmission**. Specifically, how do I read the variable **delay** from my routing source file.

```
static void
schedule_transmission(struct neighbor_queue *n)
{
  clock_time_t delay;
  int backoff_exponent; /* BE in IEEE 802.15.4 */

  backoff_exponent = MIN(n->collisions, CSMA_MAX_BE);

  /* Compute max delay as per IEEE 802.15.4: 2^BE-1 backoff periods  */
  delay = ((1 << backoff_exponent) - 1) * backoff_period();
  if(delay > 0) {
    /* Pick a time for next transmission */
    delay = random_rand() % delay;
  }

  PRINTF("csma: scheduling transmission in %u ticks, NB=%u, BE=%u\n",
      (unsigned)delay, n->collisions, backoff_exponent);
  ctimer_set(&n->transmit_timer, delay, transmit_packet_list, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, first you need declare a **delay** variable before main and second create a function like this in your csma.c:

```
Clock_time_t get_delay(void)
{
return delay;
}
```

Then call **get_delay()** function in your routing source file.